# How to add .jar files in android studio which include class name like TranslateOptions$TranslateDefault.class

Tags: android, jar, libraries

I am trying to add Google cloud Translate Library in android studio. I have some issues to add it directly through dependency. So i add jar files. But when i added jar file in lib folder it automatically exclude Classes which have '$' this character in there name. Like TranslateOptions$TranslateDefaults.class. This file shown in zip but after adding in android studio this file is not there. And program shows an error that this file is missing. Error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: edu.nic.dell.naseemchatbot, PID: 15685
>                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions$TranslateDefaults
>                                                                                   at
>   com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions.(TranslateOptions.java:147)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions.(TranslateOptions.java:39)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions$Builder.build(TranslateOptions.java:142)
>                                                                                   at
>   edu.nic.dell.naseemchatbot.ChatActivity.translateTextWithOptionsAndModel(ChatActivity.java:938)
>                                                                                   at
>   edu.nic.dell.naseemchatbot.ChatActivity$5.onClick(ChatActivity.java:272)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4766)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19683)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

and this my gradle file

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1-0.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/grpc-protobuf-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/grpc-google-common-protos-0.1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/grpc-core-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/grpc-stub-1.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-cloud-translate-1.14.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.21.0.jar')
    compile project(':google-api-services-translate-v2-rev47-1.22.0')
    compile files('libs/google-cloud-core-0.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/grpc-google-common-protos-0.1.8.jar')
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here . Check this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-translate . You only need this in gradle as depencies compile `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.14.0'`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added the dependency but it gives me a lot of duplicate errors. I actually user google cloud speech and google cloud translate service..Thats why i use .jar of them

Comment: How you tested it ?. Just delete the all the jar files you added.  For speech recognition check this .https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech . Check the root build.gradle and app build.gradle. You have to add proto in root gradle.

Comment: yes i added that file...